# Python os.rename issues: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, python-os

I've browsed around for an answer to this before posting but couldn't find one that worked for me.

So essentially what I'm doing is taking a list of selenium elements, converting them to just text in a new array, and then trying to rename the file in my downloads directory.
Upon reaching this loop I get the error.
Does the new file have to exist in order to rename it?

```
for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir("C:/Users/user/Downloads")):
    dst1 = titlelist[count] + ".mp4"
    src = 'C:/Users/user/Downloads/'+ filename
    dst = 'C:/Users/user/Downloads/'+ dst1
    os.rename(src, dst)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems good to me. Are you sure your list `titlelist` don't have characters like `\ /`? And edit the post to add full error traceback.

Comment: Nope, the titleList returns just strings. When I print the new appended paths I am able to paste them into windows explorer and it opens the video. Not sure why python isn't recognizing it.

Comment: Please attach the complete output of the error.

Answer (score 0):

To access Windows paths you need to use backslahes, and as the backslash is the escape character, you need to use two of them to include them in the string.

Instead of writing `C:/Users/user` you should write `C:\\Users\\user`

Comment: same error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\thebr\\Downloads\\AT-cm 966010388.mp4' -> 'C:\\Users\\thebr\\Downloads\\Last Call for /r/Livestreamfail Reddit Moderator Applications.mp4'

Comment: You can try to let python decide how to join paths, use `os.path.join`: `os.path.join('C:', 'Users', 'user')`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds silly, but, you may wanna check the permissions on the folder and files

```
print("Source File Permission : %s" % os.access(src ,os.W_OK))
print("Destination File Permission : %s" % os.access(dst , os.W_OK))
```

in your case I would be tempted to try something like:

```
if os.access('C:/Users/user/Downloads/', os.W_OK):
    os.rename(src, dst)
```